# Can I plot multiple statistics for different regions in a single widget on Cloudwatch Dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I tried the plot a metrics from Kinesis Firehose (KinesisMillisBehindLatest) in cloudwatch. The Firehose runs in multiple AWS regions(us-east-1, eu-west-1, us-east-2 etc). Now, I'm looking for a way to plot this metric "KinesisMillisBehindLatest" in a single widget from different regions in Cloudwatch dashboard. I tried the "duplicate a metric" option under User actions colmuns, but there is no option to set different regions. Can the Json in source be tweaked to add metrics belonging to different regions in a single widget in Cloudwatch dashboard?

From the source json below, "region" is common to all the metrics. Can I change it to specific metric?

```
{
"metrics": [
    [ "AWS/Firehose", "KinesisMillisBehindLatest", "DeliveryStreamName", "KinesisFirehoseDeliveryStreamV1" ],
    [ "...", "KinesisFirehoseDeliveryStreamV2-us-east-1" ]
    [ "AWS/Firehose", "KinesisMillisBehindLatest", "DeliveryStreamName", "KinesisFirehoseDeliveryStreamV2-eu-west-1" ]
],
"view": "timeSeries",
"stacked": false,
"region": "us-east-1"
"stat": "Average",
"period": 300,
"title": "Firehose"
```

}

Comment: I feel the pain...

Answer (score 2):

In simple words No, you can not plot multiple statistics for different regions in a single widget on CloudWatch Dashboard. Because the widgets are region based whereas CloudWatch Dashboard is global. So, you can view widgets on Dashboard added in any region.

Also, Json source code cannot be tweaked to add metrics belonging to different regions in a single widget due to its region based property.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the input. I'll create separate widget for each of the region.